# Wrong TypeName after obfuscation

Tags: vb.net, obfuscation, typename, obfuscar

I have a problem with user controls:

My VB.Net application AppliTest uses a `PlusMinus` user control.
In the application, I need at some point to treat each control according to its `TypeName`.
This works fine before obfuscation with Obfuscar ( `c.Name=PM_Large c.Type=PlusMinus` ). `c` is the control.

After obfuscation, the instance name of my user control is correct, but the `TypeName` has been obfuscated ( `c.Name=PM_Large c.Type=뢕` ). Note that all is correct with windows controls like Label, TextBox ...

I searched in the Obfuscar configuration possibilities without success.
Here are my settings for Obfuscar:

```
SkipType name="AppliTest .PlusMinus"

Var name = "KeepPublicApi" value="false"

Var name = "HidePrivateApi" value="true"

Var name = "RenameProperties" value="true"

Var name = "RenameFields" value="true"

Var name = "UseUnicodeNames" value="true"

Var name = "HideStrings" value="true"

Var name = "OptimizeMethods" value="true"

Var name = "ReuseNames" value="true"

Var name = "UseKoreanNames" value="true"
```

Is there a solution, either to make the type name protected, or to prevent Obfuscar from obfuscating the type name?

Comment: I found solution : check on type himself and not on Type Name

Comment: But this does not explain the phenomenon...